# attr_accessor vs attributes one failing the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes, attr-accessor

I'm using **her** gem in my rails app to get data from a web service backend instead of a database. This question isn't completely related to the gem though is what I believe.

My model is using `ActiveModel`

```
class Merchant

  include ActiveModel::Model

  # Add the awesomeness of Her gem
  include Her::Model

  attr_accessor :name, :type

  validates :name, presence: true

end
```

and my controller is

```
  def create

    @merchant = Merchant.new(params[:merchant])
    if @merchant.valid?
      respond_to do |format|
        if @merchant.save
          format.html { redirect_to @merchant, notice: 'Merchant was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @merchant }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @merchant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    else
     render :new
   end
  end
```

I have a form in my view like this

```
<%= form_for(@merchant) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name, "First Name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :type, "Type" %>
  <%= f.text_field :type %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now here the `attr_accessor :name, :type` is needed inside the model for the form to function properly or its throwing this error

```
undefined method `name' for #<Merchant(merchants) >
```

If i add the `attr_accessor` in the Model then `@merchant.attributes` is returning `{}`.

and this leads to the gem sending blank request to server because the gem uses `attributes` to build the request. I checked in the source of the gem.

If i don't add `attr_accessor` then everything works fine except the form throws error.

What is way to fix this error. I'd be honest i don't clearly understand how `attributes` work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [code](https://github.com/remiprev/her/blob/90e5c0d371f3cfddfb12df17a50a003b5093b54f/lib/her/model/attributes.rb#L69) suggests that if `@merchant` has an attribute called `name`, this won't happen:

```
class Merchant

  include ActiveModel::Model

  # Add the awesomeness of Her gem
  include Her::Model

  attributes :name, :type

  validates :name, presence: true

end
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of a attribute method. Thanks for pointing this solved the issue